# Find a particular word in ID or CLASS name using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm using beautifulsoup to extract information from product pages of ecommerce websites. What I'm looking to identify product pages is that:

"The CLASS or ID attribute will have 'thumb' word in them" For example: class="product_thumbs"
id = "thumbimages", etc.

currently my program is only looking for .html in the URL but that's only for one ecommerce website. But I want it to search the whole html and look for ID and CLASS attributes having "thumb" word in it.

My current code is as follows:

```
        if ".html" in childurl: # store details into product_details table if its a product page
              print("Product Found.!")
              print(childurl)
              soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(childurl).read())
              priceele = soup.find(itemprop='price').string.strip()
              brandname = soup.find(itemprop='brand').string.strip()
              nameele = soup.find(itemprop='name').string.strip()
              image = soup.find(itemprop='image').get('src')
```

Pl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with regexp pattern

```
import bs4, re
html="""<html><body><div class="foo_thumb"></div><p class="wrong"></p><a id="barthumb"></a></body></html>"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
predicates = [
    {'id' : re.compile('.*thumb.*')}, 
    {'class' : re.compile('.*thumb.*')},
]
for p in predicates:
    soup.find_all(**p)
#will print [<a id="barthumb"></a>], [<div class="foo_thumb"></div>]
```